# Maximal geodesic spheres in the "octooctonic projective plane"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

[Boris Rosenfeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_magic_square#Rosenfeld_projective_planes) claimed that the 128-dimensional compact Riemannian symmetric space on which $\mathrm{E}_8$ acts as isometries could be seen as the "octooctonionic projective plane", $(\mathbb{O} \otimes \mathbb{O})\mathrm{P}^2$.  This is the symmetric space called [EVIII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space#Classification_result) by Cartan.

This claim has always been hard to understand, since $\mathbb{O} \otimes \mathbb{O}$ is not a division algebra.  Nonetheless there seems to be something to it, as witnessed by the [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freudenthal_magic_square).

John Huerta pointed out to me that if $(\mathbb{O} \otimes \mathbb{O})\mathrm{P}^2$ really is something like an octooctonionic projective plane, we could hope it contains a lot of "octooctonionic projective lines".   We aren't sure what an "octooctonionic projective line" should be, but one naive guess is that it's $\mathbb{O} \otimes \mathbb{O}$ together with a point at infinity — and thus, a 64-sphere.

Of course there are lots of 64-spheres smoothly embedded in $(\mathbb{O} \otimes \mathbb{O})\mathrm{P}^2$, but here we want 'nice' ones, raising this question:

- **What are the maximal totally geodesic spheres in the 128-dimensional compact Riemannian symmetric space EVIII?**

For comparison, note that the octonionic projective plane $\mathbb{O}\mathrm{P}^2$ is the 16-dimensional compact Riemannian symmetric space called [FII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) by Cartan.  This contains a lot of totally geodesic 8-spheres, which can rigorously be seen as copies of $\mathbb{O}\mathrm{P}^1$.

I've come across a paper that claims to classify all maximal totally geodesic spheres in compact symmetric spaces:

- Tadashi Nagano and Makiko Sumi, [The spheres in symmetric spaces](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/hokkaido-mathematical-journal/volume-20/issue-2/The-sheres-in-symmetric-spaces/10.14492/hokmj/1381413846.full),  *Hokkaido Math. J.* **20**(2) (1991), 331–352.

However, it doesn't seem to discuss the case of EVIII.

Comment: The existence of a codimension one totally geodesic submanifold in a symmetric space implies that the symmetric space has constant curvature (I think due to Onishchik and later generalized to other homogeneous ambient spaces, I think perhaps naturally reductive homogeneous spaces). So there cannot be 15-dimensional totally geodesic spheres in $OP^2$.

Comment: Is there an error in the comment at https://mathoverflow.net/a/348222 or am I just misinterpreting it?  It begins "every geodesic sphere $S_r$, 0<r<π/2, in the octonion (or Cayley) projective plane $\mathrm{Ca}P^2$ is isometric to a canonical deformation of the round metric on $S^{15}$".

Comment: I think 'geodesic sphere' means 'distance sphere', that is, the locus of points at a given distance from a given point (distance in the metric space structure induced from  the Riemannian metric).

Comment: Oh, that explains the subscript $r$ in the sphere $S_r$ - it's the distance!

Comment: I believe it is possible to answer your question by looking closely at the Lie algebras $\mathfrak e_8\supset\mathfrak{spin}(16)$ and by computing the algebraic version of the curvature tensor, which is $\langle[u,v],[w,x]\rangle$, for $u$, $v$, $w$, $x\in\mathfrak{spin}(16)^\perp$. To be the tangent space of a totally geodesic sphere, the curvature has to have standard form on a subspace $V$ of $\mathfrak{spin}(16)^\perp$. This is a necessary condition. Also necessarily there must exist a subgroup of $E_8$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak h$ such that $\mathfrak h\cap\mathfrak{spin}(16)^\perp=V$.

Comment: @SebastianGoette - Thanks!  What's "a standard form"?  And if I want a 64-dimensional totally geodesic sphere, what dimension should $V$ (and/or $\mathfrak{h}$) be?  As a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded Lie algebra $\mathfrak{e}_8$ is the direct sum of $\mathfrak{spin}(16)$ and its 128-dimensional spinor representation, and I am able, at least in theory, to do calculations with these.

Comment: Hi @John. I mean, $V$ is the tangent space of one of these spheres at the origin, so we want $\dim V=64$. Standard form means as on a round $S^n$, that is $\langle[u,v],[w,x]\rangle=C(\langle u,w\rangle\langle v,x\rangle-\langle u,x\rangle\langle v,w\rangle)$ for some $C>0$. Also, a totally geodesic submanifold of a Riemannian symmetric space is necessarily itself symmetric. And the bad news is: there is no suitable symmetric representation of $S^{64}$. You can probably embed EVI totally geodesically in EVIII, but that's not what you want.

Comment: Okay, I get it now.  Yes, I noticed EVI, but I don't think that's what I want here.  How do you know "there is no suitable symmetric representation of $S^{64}$?

Comment: If there was, then we would have a group of rank at most $8$ that acts transitively on $S^{64}$. This group would therefore be a candidate for a special holonomy group according to Jim Simons' thesis, and hence one of $SO(n)$, $(S)U(n)$ and $Sp(n) (\cdot Sp(1))$, $G_2$ and $Spin(7)$ (which arise as holonomy groups) or $Spin(9)$ or $Sp(n) \cdot S^1$ (which don't). None of these has rank at most 8 and acts transitively on $S^{64}$.